# What local databases are available/recommended in trigger.io apps, if any?

Tags: ios, sqlite, trigger.io

I'm investigating building a mobile app with trigger.io, but I'm not finding good documentation on local database options. My app will send data to an external API, but needs to be able to store data locally as a draft (if the user is offline, the API is unavailable, whatever).

I see that there's a [prefs module](http://docs.trigger.io/en/latest/modules/prefs.html#modules-prefs) for storing data, but it does not seem like the right thing (correct me if I'm wrong). What options are recommended here? Is there something analogous to [the SQLite plugin for PhoneGap](https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin), perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably depends on what your usage patterns are going to be.

For example, `forge.prefs` could get a bit fiddly if you want to do any kind of interesting queries, but could work well if you just want to persist a single JavaScript object structure. Using `window.localStorage` is likely to have similar pros/cons.

Alternatively, you can use the WebSQL API in your JavaScript: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-3-5. You don't need to use a module for this, it should work for any Android or iOS app built with Forge. This essentially gives you an SQLite database accessible from JavaScript. To give you a feel for the API, here's an example:

```
// create db
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'example database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (id unique, text)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO foo (id, text) VALUES (1, "foobar")');
});

// query db
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM foo', [], function (tx, results) {
        var rows = results.rows;
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
            forge.logging.info("row text: " + rows.item(i).text);
        }
    });
});
```

You should be able to find some tutorials about on the web!

Comment: Very thorough and helpful! Thanks!